# xindy: formatting the first letter of the first entry of a letter group

Tags: formatting, indexing, xindy

How do I format the first letter of the first entry of a letter group in an index generated with xindy? The result should look something like this:

```
...
\indexspace

\item \textbf{b}athroom\quad{}1
\item beginner\quad{}9
\item boldface\quad{}2
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There probably is a better solution than the present hack; however, the standard setting of `xindy` writes in front of each group something like

```
\lettergroup{A}
```

it's sufficient to say

```
\long\def\lettergroup#1\item{\item\textbf}
\let\lettergroupDefault\lettergroup
```

in the preamble. A letter group will be something like

```
\lettergroup{A}
\item abc
```

and the macro ignores everything up to the first item changing it into
`\item\textbf`, so LaTeX will see

```
\item\textbf abc
```

and all will be right, as `\textbf` is a macro with one argument. For more complicated cases such as accented letters, this might be insufficient, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately (and as you suspected yourself) the solution does not work for more complicated cases like `\index{ASCC@\textsc{ascc}}` and also does not allow more complex formatting. Maybe I should ask the program authors.

Comment: If index entries have "semantic formatting", then setting their first letter in boldface seems not to be correct. At any rate, designing a general macro for this is quite difficult; it would be easier if one knew what sort of different entries can be expected.

Comment: It is strictly a matter of visual guidance for the reader signalling the beginning of a new letter group. I do not want to waste space with separate lines saying "A", "B", "C" and so on. It is probably easiest to do the formatting in the automatically generated `*.ind` file by hand.